# Странное поведение объектов

Tags: javascript, node.js

Эта проблема не дает мне покоя уже часов 6. Мне пришлось выделить этот код из основного проекта, упростить но все ровно странное поведение никуда не уходит.

Тут функция `debugging` - в нее приходит объект `msg`. В этом объекте есть `id`. В массив `chats` добавляется новый чат с помощью деструктуризации, устанавливая `id` для чата из полученного `msg.chat.id`. Объекты `msg` это как бы сообщения пользователей с разных чатов, у каждого чата свой `id`. В каждом чате есть своя переменная `chat.access.attempts` и она ровна `4`. Так вот, с каждым сообщение от пользователя `chat.access.attempts` уменьшается на единицу, притом только для текущего чата.

Я вызываю функцию `debugging` с тремя разными объектами `msg`, они независимы друг от друга, но я получаю, что `chat.access.attempts = 1` причем у каждого, когда должен быть `3` у каждого, так как `debugging` с каждой `msg` вызывалась только один раз. Запустил этот код в браузере, тоже самое. ChatGPT тоже не знает, в чем проблема, его результатом в консоли было то, что все `chat.access.attempts` равны 3, и что это очень странно.
Может я ошибся в чем-то? Просто я действительно в тупике.

Вот консольный вывод:

```
чат индекс 0 чат id 11111 попыток 4
чат индекс 1 чат id 22222 попыток 3
чат индекс 2 чат id 33333 попыток 2
[
  {
    id: 11111,
    test: 0,
    access: { invalidPassTimeout: null, attempts: 1, accessed: false }
  },
  {
    id: 22222,
    test: 0,
    access: { invalidPassTimeout: null, attempts: 1, accessed: false }
  },
  {
    id: 33333,
    test: 0,
    access: { invalidPassTimeout: null, attempts: 1, accessed: false }
  }
]
```

Вот код:

```js
/////////////////////////////////////Установка чатов///////////////////////////////////////////////////
let chats = [];
let initialChat = {
    id: null,
    access: {
        invalidPassTimeout: null,
        attempts: 4,
        accessed: false
    }
}

let msg = {
    chat: {
        id: 11111
    }
}

let msg2 = {
    chat: {
        id: 22222
    }
}

let msg3 = {
    chat: {
        id: 33333
    }
}

function debugging(msg){
    // Добавления чата в список открытых чатов бота
    if(chats.find(chat => chat.id === msg.chat.id) === undefined){
        chats = [...chats, {...initialChat, id: msg.chat.id}];
    }

    //используем этот чат
    let chatIndx = chats.findIndex(item => item.id === msg.chat.id);
    let chat = {...chats[chatIndx]};
    let options;

    console.log("чат индекс " + chatIndx + " чат id " + chat.id + " попыток " + chat.access.attempts);
    chat.access.attempts--;

    //обновляем массив chats
    chats.splice(chatIndx, 1, chat);
}

debugging(msg)
debugging(msg2)
debugging(msg3)

console.log(chats);
```

Comment: `chat.access.attempts--;` так вы же сами и уменьшаете...

Comment: В javaScript каждый объект существует в единственном экземпляре и передается по ссылке, а спред оператор выполняет только верхнеуровневое клонирование. Таким образом, access имеет ссылку на один единственный объект и каждый вызов функции его уменьшает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы хоть и деструктуризируете `initialChat`, но вложенный в этот объект `access` остается одним и тем же. То есть у любого объекта `...initialChat` ссылка на один объект `access`. По этому изменяя у одного `chat` значение в объекте `access` вы меняете его у всех.

Можно воспользоваться глобальной функцией [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone), которая возвращает полностью скопированный объект.

В вашем коде это выглядело бы примерно так:

```js
chats = [...chats, {...structuredClone(initialChat), id: msg.chat.id}];
```